# What public pool is this in Kansas?

Tags: photo-identification, photo, 1920s, kansas

I have the below two pictures from about June 1923, most likely in Hutchinson, Kansas, but possibly in Wichita, Kansas.[image][image]

Can anyone identify the exact pool?  I found [this article](https://www.kshs.org/kansapedia/swimming-pools/17223) stating that public swimming pools starting being built for the first time in the 1920s.  Perhaps this is at [Carey Municipal Park in Hutchinson](http://neplains.com/kansashutchinson-careyparkmunicipalswimmingpool1940s.aspx)?[image]

Comment: Are you certain on the date? They look later than 1920s to me but if you're sure...

Comment: @HarryVervet Based upon the two identified kids, the date is pretty certain, plus or minus a year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably won't be too helpful - but there are pictures of a few swimming pools in kansas.

http://www.kansasmemory.org/locate.php?categories=567&query=swimming+pools&restrict=all

possibly they might be able to point you in the right direction.